# Unable to read csv file by Anaconda IDE

Tags: python, csv, pandas

My Anaconda IDE is unable to read csv file using `panda.read_csv()` function.

File name is baseball which is kept at location *C:\Users\Firdaus\Desktop*

I have written following code:

```
# Import pandas as pd
import pandas as pd
# Import the cars.csv data as Base
Base = pd.read_csv('C:\Users\Firdaus\Desktop\baseball.csv')
# Print out Base
print(Base)
```

Error is:

> SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes
>   in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In regular python strings, the \U character combination signals an extended Unicode codepoint escape.
You can use one of the following:

```
r'C:\Users\Firdaus\Desktop\baseball.csv' #r stands for raw strings
'C:\\Users\\Firdaus\\Desktop\\baseball.csv' #using double slashes
'C:/Users/Firdaus/Desktop/baseball.csv' #using forward slashes
```

Hope this helps.